# Can MS Exchange provide a solution for multiple domains?

Tags: domain, hosted-exchange

Is it possible to have an Exchange Server solution that allows for multiple email domains? I would like to make use of push email but also want to retain the scheduling features of Outlook/Exchange integration. The only problem is I use multiple business domains and need to be able to respond from each of them from Outlook and my Smartphone (iOS or Android).

From everything I have seen so far it looks like Exchange doesn't allow email to be sent out from different aliases. Can hosted Exchange solutions do this?

Answer (score 5):

Exchange only allows sending from the primary SMTP address of a mailbox. This limitation carries over to ActiveSync.

In Outlook you can solve this problem by creating one mailbox per email address, giving your "main" mailbox Send_as privileges, and using the "Alternate Recipient" on those mailboxes to deliver all incoming messages to your "main" mailbox. Outlook will then let you pick one of those mailboxes to send as.

However, nearly every phone I've ever used only allows for one ActiveSync account, and does not allow you to switch the From address to another mailbox.

Comment: Both iPhone and Android from 2.2 and upwards supports multiple ActiveSync accounts.

Comment: @longneck Blackberry always had that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

MS Exchange is capable of dealing with multiple domains - we do it all the time. Once you have the domain purchased and the MX records pointing to your Exchange server, you can modify the recipient policy of your server to allow for multiple domains.

Once this is done, you can modify your user in Active Directory to have multiple e-mail addresses (user@domain1.com / user@domain2.com, etc). While each e-mail address and domain is different the mail is all routed to one mailbox, which allows for a single point of administration.

I can't speak as to whether hosted solutions will allow this (although I assume it would). As for sending it from multiple "From" addresses, this blog shows a rather clever [McGuyver](http://modernerd.com/post/535350679/solved-gmail-ipad-iphone-and-multiple-from) on how to achieve that.